# Recording in stereo using Flash/Actionscript 3

Tags: audio, actionscript, flash-cs5

Just want to verify what I'm reading and seeing- it appears that Actionscript 3 is only capable of recording in mono.  It will record from devices other than the mic, but, even if the device is outputting stereo, I only get mono.

Is there a way around that?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to record in Stereo using Actionscript 3.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. Damn!